# How to explicitly call TIBDataSet.RefreshSQL

Tags: sql, database, delphi

I have list of records in TIBDataSet (Embarcadero Delphi) and I need to locate and modify one record in this list. There is chance that underlying database record has been changed by other queries and operations since TIBDataSet had been opened. Therefor I would like to call RefreshSQL for this one record (to get the latest data) before making any changes and before making post. Is it possible to do so and how?

I am not concerned about state of other records and I am sure that the record under consideration will always be updated and those updates will be commited before I need to changes this record from TIBDataSet.

As far as I understand then RefreshSQL is used for automatic retrieve of changes after TIBDataSet has posted upates to database. But I need manual (explicit) retrieval of the latest state before doing updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a TButton to your form and add the following code to its OnClick handler:

```
procedure TForm1.btnRefreshClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IBQuery1.Refresh;  // or whatever your IBX dataset is called
end;
```

and set a breakpoint on it.

Then run your app and another one (e.g. 2nd instance of it) and change a row in the second app, and commit it back to the db.

Navigate to the changed row in your app and click btnRefresh and use the debugger to trace execution.

You'll find that `TDataSet.Refresh` calls its `InternalRefresh` which in turn calls `TIBCustomDataSet.InternalRefresh`.  That calls `inherited InternalRefresh`, which does nothing, followed by `TIBCustomDataSet.InternalRefreshRow`.  If you trace into that, you'll find that it contructs a temporary IB query to retrieve the current row from the server, which should give you what you want before making changes yourself.

So that should do what you want.  The problem is, it can be thoroughly confusing trying to monitor the data in two applications because they may be in different transaction states.  So you are rather dependent on other users' apps "playing the transactional game" with you, so everyone sees a consistent view of the data.